# Sql selection of text file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I am new in SQL and need a small help in solving this. I have a column which has a file path name "C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\AMSO_CLAIMS_YYYYMMDD.txt".

And, I need to create a column (Dataset)with data of file name without a date.

Here are the following examples of my data

"C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\AMSO_CLAIMS_YYYYMMDD.txt" - > New Column (Dataset) value is AMSO_Claims

""C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\V2_HC_ADV_CLAIMS_YYYYMMDD.txt" -> New column (Dataset) value will be V2_HC_ADV_CLAIMS

""C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\V2_MEDICA_PHA_CLAIMS_YYYYMMDD.txt" -> New column (Dataset) value will be V2_MEDICA_PHA_CLAIMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Declare @T Table (Filename varchar(100))
insert into @T(Filename) values
('C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\AMSO_CLAIMS_YYYYMMDD.txt'),
('C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\V2_HC_ADV_CLAIMS_YYYYMMDD.txt'),
('C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\V2_MEDICA_PHA_CLAIMS_YYYYMMDD.txt')

SELECT Filename
    ,NewColumn = replace(substring(filename, 1, len(filename) - charindex('_', REVERSE(filename))), 'C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\', '')
    ,NewColumnYYYYMMDD = reverse(substring(reverse(filename),1,charindex('_',REVERSE(filename))-1))
FROM @T
```

---

```
| Filename                                                              | NewColumn            | NewColumnYYYYMMDD |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------|-------------------|
| C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\AMSO_CLAIMS_YYYYMMDD.txt          | AMSO_CLAIMS          | YYYYMMDD.txt      |
| C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\V2_HC_ADV_CLAIMS_YYYYMMDD.txt     | V2_HC_ADV_CLAIMS     | YYYYMMDD.txt      |
| C:\Users\akumar\Desktop_Claim Files\V2_MEDICA_PHA_CLAIMS_YYYYMMDD.txt | V2_MEDICA_PHA_CLAIMS | YYYYMMDD.txt      |
```

Comment: Yes, Now I also want to add a new column with the YYYYMMDD in the same table

Comment: @AvinashKumar - I updated the example for the YYYYMMDD column.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.